Relationship Between Recursion and PGFs
Original Question: I have often seen people use Recursion in the context of PGF (Probability-generating function):
$$
G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k s^k
$$
$$ G_n(s) = G(G_{n-1}(s)) $$
I never understood fully the relationship between Recursion and PGFs, so this is my attempt to dissect it
Part 1: I created a simple example involving the sum of two coins being flipped. Here, $k$ represents the possible (total) score values, and $p_k$ represents the probability of seeing that score.

Coin 1:  Probability of heads: $p_1$, Score for heads: $s_1$, Score for tails: $s_2$

Coin 2: Probability of heads: $p_2$, Score for heads: $s_3$,  Score for tails: $s_4$


Part 2: Next, I tried to demonstrate these two properties that are useful in analyzing PGF's:
Property 1: There is a special property for the sum of two random variables - the resulting PGF is the multiplication of the individual PGFs':

PGF for Coin 1:

$$ G_1(x) = p_1x^{s_1} + (1-p_1)x^{s_2} $$

PGF for Coin 2:

$$ G_2(x) = p_2x^{s_3} + (1-p_2)x^{s_4} $$

PGF for the sum of scores from both coins:

$$ \begin{aligned}
G_{total}(x) &= G_1(x) \cdot G_2(x) \\
&= (p_1x^{s_1} + (1-p_1)x^{s_2})(p_2x^{s_3} + (1-p_2)x^{s_4}) \\
&= p_1p_2x^{s_1+s_3} + p_1(1-p_2)x^{s_1+s_4} + (1-p_1)p_2x^{s_2+s_3} + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)x^{s_2+s_4}
\end{aligned} $$
Property 2:
For a simple random variable X with the following probability distribution:
$$ P(X = 0) = p, \quad P(X = 1) = 1-p $$
PGF for 1 turn:
$$ G_X(s) = p + (1-p)s $$
For the sum of two independent trials, Y = X₁ + X₂:
$$ \begin{aligned}
G_Y(s) &= E[s^Y] = E[s^{X_1 + X_2}] \\
&= E[s^{X_1} \cdot s^{X_2}] \\
&= E[s^{X_1}] \cdot E[s^{X_2}] \quad \text{(due to independence)} \\
&= G_X(s) \cdot G_X(s) \\
&= [p + (1-p)s]^2 \\
&= p^2 + 2p(1-p)s + (1-p)^2s^2
\end{aligned} $$
Additionally, we can check that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(p + (1-p)s)^2 &= [p + (1-p)s][p + (1-p)s] \\
&= p \cdot p + p \cdot (1-p)s + (1-p)s \cdot p + (1-p)s \cdot (1-p)s \\
&= p^2 + p(1-p)s + (1-p)ps + (1-p)^2s^2 \\
&= p^2 + p(1-p)s + p(1-p)s + (1-p)^2s^2 \\
&= p^2 + 2p(1-p)s + (1-p)^2s^2
\end{aligned}
$$
This shows that  $[p + (1-p)s]²$  equals $p² + 2p(1-p)s + (1-p)²s²$
and that:
$$ G_X(s)^2 = [p + (1-p)s]^2 = p^2 + 2p(1-p)s + (1-p)^2s^2 = G_Y(s) $$
And in General, for n turns:
$$ G_{n}(s) = [G_X(s)]^n = [p + (1-p)s]^n $$
$$
G_n(s) = [G_X(s)]^n = [p + (1-p)s]^n = G(s) \cdot G(s) \cdot \ldots \cdot G(s) \quad \text{(n times)}
$$
$$
G_n(s) = \underbrace{G(s) \cdot G(s) \cdot \ldots \cdot G(s)}_{\text{n times}}
$$
$$
G_n(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^X] \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^X] \quad \text{(n times)}
$$
$$
G_n(s) = \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[s^X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^X] \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^X]}_{\text{n times}}
$$
$$ G_{n}(s) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^{n-k} (1-p)^k s^k $$
Part 3: Based on these two properties, I tried to write the PGF's for different turns:

PGF for 1 turn:

$$ G_1(x) = (p_1x^{s_1} + (1-p_1)x^{s_2})(p_2x^{s_3} + (1-p_2)x^{s_4}) $$

PGF for 2 turns:

$$ G_2(x) = [(p_1x^{s_1} + (1-p_1)x^{s_2})(p_2x^{s_3} + (1-p_2)x^{s_4})]^2 $$

PGF for 3 turns:

$$ G_3(x) = [(p_1x^{s_1} + (1-p_1)x^{s_2})(p_2x^{s_3} + (1-p_2)x^{s_4})]^3 $$
Then I expanded:

Expanded PGF for 1 turn:

$$ G_1(x) = p_1p_2x^{s_1+s_3} + p_1(1-p_2)x^{s_1+s_4} + (1-p_1)p_2x^{s_2+s_3} + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)x^{s_2+s_4} $$

Expanded PGF for 2 turns:

$$ \begin{aligned}
G_2(x) = & (p_1p_2)^2x^{2(s_1+s_3)} + 2p_1p_2(p_1(1-p_2))x^{2s_1+s_3+s_4} + 2p_1p_2((1-p_1)p_2)x^{s_1+s_2+2s_3} \\
& + 2p_1p_2((1-p_1)(1-p_2))x^{s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4} + (p_1(1-p_2))^2x^{2(s_1+s_4)} \\
& + 2(p_1(1-p_2))((1-p_1)p_2)x^{s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4} + 2(p_1(1-p_2))((1-p_1)(1-p_2))x^{s_1+s_2+2s_4} \\
& + ((1-p_1)p_2)^2x^{2(s_2+s_3)} + 2((1-p_1)p_2)((1-p_1)(1-p_2))x^{s_2+2s_3+s_4} \\
& + ((1-p_1)(1-p_2))^2x^{2(s_2+s_4)}
\end{aligned} $$
I got stuck trying to identify the PGF for 1 turn within the PGF of 2 turns, so I tried to show this a different way.
Part 4:
For the sum of n i.i.d. random variables, and $G(s)$ is the PGF for a single random variable. The final recursion formula should be:
$$ G_n(s) = G(G_{n-1}(s)) $$
$$ G_n(s) = E[s^{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}] $$
$$ G_n(s) = E[s^{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{n-1}} \cdot s^{X_n}] $$
Due to the independence of the variables, we can separate the expectations:
$$ G_n(s) = E[s^{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{n-1}}] \cdot E[s^{X_n}] $$
The first term is the definition of $G_{n-1}(s)$, and the second term is $G(s)$. Thus:
$$ G_n(s) = G(G_{n-1}(s)) $$
Part 5: Going back to the coin flip problem (assume a single coin), we can now see that the PGF for a single flip is:
$$ G(s) = p \cdot s^1 + (1-p) \cdot s^0 = ps + (1-p) $$
For 1 flip: $G_1(s) = G(s) = ps + (1-p)$
For 2 flips:
$$ \begin{aligned}
G_2(s) &= G(G_1(s)) = G(ps + (1-p)) \\
&= p(ps + (1-p)) + (1-p) \\
&= p^2s + p(1-p) + (1-p) \\
&= p^2s + (1-p^2)
\end{aligned} $$
For 3 flips:
$$ \begin{aligned}
G_3(s) &= G(G_2(s)) = G(p^2s + (1-p^2)) \\
&= p(p^2s + (1-p^2)) + (1-p) \\
&= p^3s + p(1-p^2) + (1-p) \\
&= p^3s + (1-p^3)
\end{aligned} $$
And for n flips:
$$ G_n(s) = p^ns + (1-p^n) $$
Conclusion: In hindsight, I think I significantly overcomplicated this problem - but I think this (partly) justifies the recursion property of PGF's?

What is the definition of $G_n(x)$? Im confused as to what general fact you are trying to prove. Also, in part 4, the equation $G_n(s)=G(G_{n-1}(s))$ comes out of nowhere. None of the work in parts 1 to 3 suggests function composition of PGFs.

@ Mike: I was just trying to understand why this is true? Gn(s)=G(Gn−1(s))

@wulsa Well, I do not know why it is true, either. And there is nothing in the context you have given to suggest it is true. Maybe it is false? Or maybe you need to give more context.

A reference to a example of $G(G_{n-1}(s))=G_n(s)$ in a probability context would help clarify what's going on.

@MikeEarnest: Do you know if what I have done here is correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached
